# NSData getBytes provides different results in simulator than on device

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I am sending data from a self-written server backend to my iOS device.
The application works fine in the iOS Simulator but not on the device.
For example: I'm sending the integer value 4 - on the Simulator I get 4 but on the device it's 1024. I searched the whole internet but didn't find any solution, so maybe someone can help me here. I don't think it's an endian issue cause i already payed attention to it.

This is the code:

```
int someintvalue = 0;

uint8_t firstBuffer[4];

[inputStream read:firstBuffer maxLength: sizeof(firstBuffer)];
NSMutableData *data1 = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:firstBuffer   
                                                     length:sizeof(firstBuffer)];

NSRange rng = NSMakeRange(0, 4);
[data1 getBytes:&someintvalue range:rng];


someintvalue = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(someintvalue);
NSLog(@"Got %i Value", someintvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're byte-swapping incorrectly. `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()` swaps from the "host" endianness to big-endian. This is backwards. You probably meant to use `CFSwapInt32BigToHost()`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem... I tried to change it, but in fact it doesn't change anything. In the simulator it still works fine - on the device I get wrong values

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for this problem.

Ran into the same issue:

- The length is incorrect in this case. iOS keeps reading and rewriting the last byte in this case.